# Is the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}( a^{\frac{1}{k}}-1)$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, riemann-integration

Assume that $a \gt 1$ .

Is the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}( a^{\frac{1}{k}}-1)$ convergent?

Note : I think it must be related to a test ... Is there a test to confirm that a series converges ? Can we say this series converges because $a^{\frac{1}{k}}$ does?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$a^{1/k} - 1 = e^{(\log a)/k} -1\approx\frac{\log a}k$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
$$a^{1/k}-1=\int_0^{1/k}a^x\ln a\,dx\sim\frac{\ln a}{k}$$